# SQL Select data and fill the eventual gaps - query

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine the dataset:

```
ID, PRICE
12345, 100.1
12346, 101.1
12347, 100.2
12348, 100.0
12352, 100.3 <- GAP
12355, 100.4 <- GAP
12356, 100.6
12357, 103.2
...
```

Question:
I need to continously select next value until the end of the dataset.
How do i select next value by ID and ensure that if there is a GAP i am returned the last known value so:

```
12348 if i want 12349
12348 if i want 12350
12348 if i want 12351
12352 if i want 12352
```

Thank you very much for any input into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE ID <= 12350
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It probably won't perform very well, but it looks like it will do what you want.